# Vue.js authorization issue

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I am trying to develop an application using Laravel5.5 and Vue.js2. I am getting below error

[image]

I think vue.js can't send authentication token to Laravel. I am trying to send authentication token from vue.js is like below

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken()
```

I placed this code in `main.js` file. I have a package in vue.js named `Auth.js`. But it is not working.

- UPDATE

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Auth from './packages/auth/Auth.js'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(Auth)

Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken()

Vue.config.productionTip = false

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
    if(Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            next({
            path: '/dashboard'
            })
    } else {next()}
    }
    else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.Authenti)) {
    if(!Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            next({
            path: '/'
            })
    } else {next()}
    } else {next()}
})


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: have you tried to check if your server has a `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');`

Comment: Can you put here the code of your `main.js` and the `model or controller` you want to access in your back-end

Comment: Thanks @JohnReyM.Baylen. I am using Laravel 5.5. I have following configuration in `config/cors.php`. ` 'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,`. 

Thanks

Comment: I am getting expected output while I put my `route` outside of this group `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {`. Thanks